# How to remove a document from the capped collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I try to  remove a document in collection in MongoDB . It didn't remove because the collection is capped . My question is why? And is there a solution or other function can remove the document in this case?

Answer (score 7):

No You cannot delete documents from a capped collection. And there is no possible workaround. The only thing you can do is [`drop()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/#db.collection.drop) the collection.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use remove function for capped collection. There are some [`restrictions`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220280/how-to-remove-document-from-capped-collection-in-mongodb) on capped collections. Also you can refer this [`document`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) for capped collection in mongoDB.