# when remove document from capped collection in mongoDB, it through an error?

Tags: mongodb

I am learning mongoDB for my new project. I created a capped collection but I am getting an error while I am trying to remove document from capped collection in mongoDB which is below,

> db.mycol.remove({"_id":ObjectId("57bef716e5ff2cbb540e403b")})
>
> WriteResult({
>           "nRemoved" : 0,
>           "writeError" : {
>                   "code" : 20,
>                   "errmsg" : "cannot remove from a capped collection: mytestdb.myc
>   ol"
>           }
>   })

Please help me out from this.

Thank you in advance.!

Comment: Possibly a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/33048282/3081659

Answer (score 1):

Capped collections do not support `remove` documents , and have few other [restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/core/capped-collections/#recommendations-and-restrictions) as well to make them performant in the capped usecase.

> You cannot delete documents from a capped collection. To remove all
>   documents from a collection, use the drop() method to drop the
>   collection

Comment: Thank you @DhruvPathak for this suggestion, that means If I would to perform any delete or update operation then I never declare collection as capped, right?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation:

"Document Deletion

You cannot delete documents from a capped collection. To remove all documents from a collection, use the drop() method to drop the collection and recreate the capped collection."

Which means you need to delete the whole collection then recreate it.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/

Comment: Thank you @Eve for this valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Cause: your Collection is Capped, can not do this action. Details: [Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/#restrictions-and-recommendations)

Addition, check your **Collection is Capped?** by command:

```
db.mycol.isCapped()
```

check your MongoDB version by command:

```
db.version()
```

**[Solve]**
Create a new Collection not Capped and copy all your document.

Copy, replace your collection name and paste in your terminal.

```
// replace <mycol> by <your collections name>
db.createCollection( "mycol_temp")
var cur = db.mycol.find()
while (cur.hasNext()) {
  mycol = cur.next();
  db.mycol_temp.insert(logItem);
}
db.mycol.drop()
db.mycol_temp.renameCollection("mycol")
```

Now, update() or remove() document is accepted via re-arranging collections.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove documents from a capped collection.

If your business logic requires to remove items from capped collection, you can just mark as deleted (logical deletion adding a boolean field)

We implemented this for a queue years ago. Nowadays we  switched to kafka.